# Database items with more than one categories

Tags: php, mysql, database, phpmyadmin

I'm creating a filtering system with 3 steps and it works for now but now I want to have items with more categories. All category_ids are INTs. Do I have to change this or whats the best option to make this. [image]

[image]
This is my solution for now. So I have a column (redundancy) for separating the partner which are more than one time in the database, so I'm not getting double results if I filter for all.

But I want (if possible) the possibility to write more categories in the category_id/subcategory_id/subcategory2_id so I don't need to write one partner many times in the database and still can fetch it in PHP.

Here's my database as code:

```
-- phpMyAdmin SQL Dump
-- version 5.0.2
-- https://www.phpmyadmin.net/
--
-- Host: localhost
-- Erstellungszeit: 19. Okt 2020 um 11:36
-- Server-Version: 10.4.13-MariaDB
-- PHP-Version: 7.4.8

SET SQL_MODE = "NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO";
START TRANSACTION;
SET time_zone = "+00:00";


/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@@CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@@CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION=@@COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
/*!40101 SET NAMES utf8mb4 */;

--
-- Datenbank: `partnerfilter`
--

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Tabellenstruktur für Tabelle `partner`
--

CREATE TABLE `partner` (
`partner_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
`category_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
`subcategory_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
`subcategory2_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
`partner_name` text NOT NULL,
`partner_logo` text NOT NULL DEFAULT '[Kein Bild vorhanden]',
`partner_link` text NOT NULL,
`status` tinyint(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT 1 COMMENT '1=Active | 0=Inactive',
`redundancy` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT 1 COMMENT '1 = First Object\r\n0 = Doubled Object'
 ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;

 --
 -- RELATIONEN DER TABELLE `partner`:
 --   `category_id`
 --       `categories` -> `category_id`
 --   `subcategory_id`
 --       `subcategories` -> `subcategory_id`
 --   `subcategory2_id`
 --       `subcategories2` -> `subcategory2_id`
 --

 --
 -- Daten für Tabelle `partner`
 --

 INSERT INTO `partner` (`partner_id`, `category_id`, `subcategory_id`, `subcategory2_id`, `partner_name`, `partner_logo`, `partner_link`, `status`, `redundancy`) VALUES
 (2, 2, 2, 4, 'Udo Förster', 'url', '/udofoerster', 1, 1),
 (3, 2, 2, 5, 'Testfirma', '[kein Logo vorhanden]', '/testfirma', 1, 1),
 (4, 2, 2, 6, 'Brüninghoff', 'https://assets.kununu.com/images/images_logos/bruninghoff-gmbh-co-kg-194df.gif', '/brueninghoff', 1, 1),
 (5, 2, 2, 4, 'Naturi', '[Kein Logo vorhanden]', '/naturi', 1, 1),
 (6, 1, 6, 15, 'BlowerDoor', 'url', '/blowerdoor', 1, 1),
 (7, 1, 9, 15, 'ante', 'https://www.ante-holz.de/fileadmin/_processed_/csm_Ante-Logo_bc1031754d.gif', '/ante', 1, 1),
 (8, 1, 9, 15, 'ABA', 'url', '/aba-holz', 1, 1),
 (9, 2, 13, 15, 'Udo Förster', 'url', '/udofoerster', 1, 0);

 --
 -- Indizes der exportierten Tabellen
 --

 --
 -- Indizes für die Tabelle `partner`
 --
ALTER TABLE `partner`
 ADD PRIMARY KEY (`partner_id`),
 ADD KEY `category_id` (`category_id`),
 ADD KEY `subcategory_id` (`subcategory_id`),
 ADD KEY `subcategory2_id` (`subcategory2_id`);

--
-- AUTO_INCREMENT für exportierte Tabellen
--

--
-- AUTO_INCREMENT für Tabelle `partner`
--
ALTER TABLE `partner`
 MODIFY `partner_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, 
 AUTO_INCREMENT=10;

--
-- Constraints der exportierten Tabellen
--

--
-- Constraints der Tabelle `partner`
--
ALTER TABLE `partner`
 ADD CONSTRAINT `partner_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`category_id`) REFERENCES `categories` (`category_id`),
 ADD CONSTRAINT `partner_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`subcategory_id`) REFERENCES `subcategories` (`subcategory_id`),
 ADD CONSTRAINT `partner_ibfk_3` FOREIGN KEY (`subcategory2_id`) REFERENCES `subcategories2` (`subcategory2_id`);
 COMMIT;

 /*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
 /*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
 /*!40101 SET COLLATION_CONNECTION=@OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
```

Thanks :)

Comment: Please post tables structure as text, not pictures

Comment: I didn't wrote it. How can I see the tables as text?

Comment: Just run query `SHOW CREATE TABLE your_table_name;` and copy result here

Comment: Just updated ...

Answer (score 0):

This is about many to many data structure. One partner may be belonged to many subcategories, such each of subcategories may have many partners, right?
The classic solution for this is three table solution:

```
CREATE TABLE `partners` (
    `id` int,
    -- ...
    -- rest partner fields
    -- ...
    PRIMARY KEY(`id`)
);

CREATE TABLE `subcategories` (
    `id` int,
    -- ...
    -- rest subcategory fields
    -- ...
    PRIMARY KEY(`id`)
);

CREATE TABLE `partner_subcategories` (
    `partner_id` int,
    `subcategory_id` int,
    PRIMARY KEY(`partner_id`, `subcategory_id`),
    KEY `partner_fk` (`partner_id`),
    CONSTRAINT `partner_fk` FOREIGN KEY (`partner_id`) REFERENCES `partners`(`id`),
    KEY `subcategory_fk` (`subcategory_id`),
    CONSTRAINT `subcategory_fk` FOREIGN KEY (`subcategory_id`) REFERENCES `subcategories` (`id`)
);
```

Here the fiddle [SQLize.online](https://sqlize.online/?phpses=null&sqlses=43305c4200c1897fdc58e94cc5ab0501&php_version=null&sql_version=mysql80)

Comment: So now I have the tables: categories, subcategories, subcategories2 and partner. And now I have to create 3 more?

Comment: If the partner can be belong to more then one category add `partner_categories`. If it can be belong to more then one subcategory create table `partner_subcategories` and so on ...

Comment: Is your subcategory belongs to one category?

Comment: 'categories' is connected with 'subcategories' and 'subcategories' is connected with 'subcategories2'. These three tables are the filter steps (category dropdowns), so when you choose a category from 'category' you get more categories from 'subcategory' and so on. And these three tables are connected with the table 'partner' to fetch final results. I hope you understand what I mean and I want to say I'm new in this so please try to explain so I can understand it. :)

Comment: Look is this fiddle make sense: https://sqlize.online/?phpses=null&sqlses=99e530df2c108199cfad610c8d9a5f59&php_version=null&sql_version=mysql80